# How can I apply the material from a picture to a mesh (from the view of the camera)?

Tags: modeling, texturing, 3d-view, camera

I have a very simple plane in my 3d workspace and I want to apply a texture from a picture to the plane and I want to keep the texture just as the camera sees it (of course :) )
**How do I do this?**
[image]

Comment: please show the picture and your 3D scene

Comment: I updated the post and added a picture!

Comment: what if you unwrap the plane and put its 4 vertices on the picture in the UV Editor?

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean, try positioning your camera where you want it, select the plane (in edit mode), press U (unwrap) and select "Project from view". Then apply the material.

Answer (score 2):

I know two methods for this:

- In edit mode you can press <kbd>U</kbd> and then click *project from view* in the unwrapping menu.
- You could use the Project From View modifier with the camera as a
  projector.

More information on Project From View modifier at the manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html/)

Note that with both of these options you need to subdivide the mesh in edit mode or with the Subdivision Subsurface modifier before using this method.